# Resize Bootstrap dialog-modal according to the video which is inside it

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I cannot know the dimensions of the video as i'll be getting the video from another source, i wanna know if there's a way when i open the Bootstrap modal it automatically resizes itself according the video inside of it, also I'm using video tag and not iframe because i also cannot know what type of video I'll be getting.
Even the video is not showing in the modal but the  audio is there.

```
<script>
function firstmodal(ele){
$(ele).next().modal('show');

}

</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " onclick="firstmodal(this)" >Play</button>

     <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" >


            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Click on the Play button</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body" ><video controls preload="none"> <source src="http://dl5.downloadha.com/hosein/Movie/Series/Arrow%20S04/Arrow.S04E23.Web-DL.x265.720p-PSA%20%28www.Downloadha.com%29.mkv"  ></video></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: done @Karin .. now even the video is not showing, just the audio is playing